# Suggest correct overload of NewFamilyInstance

Tags: c#, revit-api

Suggest me the overload of NewFamilyInstance I can use in my case.

I have written a method which add some element to the `Finish[1] & Finish[2]` layer of wall using these two overloads:

1. ```
   public FamilyInstance NewFamilyInstance(XYZ location,
                                           FamilySymbol symbol,
                                           StructuralType structuralType)
   ```
2. ```
   public FamilyInstance NewFamilyInstance(XYZ location,
                                           FamilySymbol symbol,
                                           Wall wall,
                                           StructuralType structuralType)
   ```

It is working fine for the wall which is horizontal(If we see the wall from top view) but for wall at particular angle the element remains horizontal.

I have attached an image representing both the cases mentioned above.

This is the overload I used

```
foreach (double layerOffsett in layerOffsets )
{
    int counter = 0;
    oldStartPoint = p0 + layerOffsett * vectoPerpendicularTothewall;

    FamilyInstance instance2 = document.Create.NewFamilyInstance(
                                   oldStartPoint, 
                                   symbol,
                                   wall,
                                   StructuralType.NonStructural);

    for (int j = 1; j < n2 - 1; j++)
    {
        XYZ newStartPoint = new XYZ(oldStartPoint.X + 4
                                        * normalizeVectorAlongTheWall.X,
                                    oldStartPoint.Y + 4
                                        * normalizeVectorAlongTheWall.Y,
                                    oldStartPoint.Z + 4
                                        * normalizeVectorAlongTheWall.Z);

        instance2 = document.Create.NewFamilyInstance(
                        newStartPoint,
                        symbol,
                        wall,
                        StructuralType.NonStructural);

        oldStartPoint = newStartPoint;
    }

    counter++;
}
```

The element I am placing is not hosted to wall.

I want these elements to automatically rotate and adjust itself in the Finish layer of wall.

Is there any way or do I have to individually rotate them?

[image: Here is the image of the both the wall with elements populated in them]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this [resource](https://www.revitapidocs.com/2020/3968f4e8-759c-f975-6c1f-7de42be633ed.htm).

You can insert the family instance and roate with the same angle as the wall.